# Different ( Is it equivalent?) hypothesis for stronger version of Goursat's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions

Ahlfors, states that

**Theorem:** Let $f(z)$ be analytic on the set $R'$ obtained from a rectangle $R$ (interior and on the boundary of the rectangle) by omitting a finite number of interior points $a_i$. If it is true that

$\lim_{z\to a_i}(z-a_i)f(z)=0$ then the integration of $f(z)$ along $R$ is zero.

Some other books use the hypothesis, Let $f(z)$ be analytic on the set $R'$ obtained from a rectangle $R$ by omitting a finite number of interior points $a_i$ and f(z) is continuous on $R$ (inside and on the boundary of the rectangle), then integration of $f(z)$ over the rectangle R is zero.

***My question is :*** "Is it equivalent that "$f(z)$ is continuous at $a_i$ and analytic everywhere expect a_i" and  "$\lim_{z\to a_i}(z-a_i)f(z)=0$ and analytic everywhere expect a_i" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since all $a_i$ are isolated in $R$, those statements equivalent, due to [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem).

Comment: I think Riemann's Removable Singularity theorem says  $\lim_{z\to a_i}(z-a_i)f(z)=0 \implies lim_{z\to a}f(z)$ exists, it need not be equal to $f(a)$, that is need not be continuous. @Martin R

Comment: @Babai: If $f$ is analytic on $R'$ then it is not *defined* in the $a_j$. If $\lim_{z\to a_i}(z-a_i)f(z)=0 $ then $\lim_{z\to a_j}f(z)$ exists, to that $f(a_j)$ can be defined as  that limit, making $f$ continuous. – I'll edit the answer later, when I have more time, to make it more precise.

Comment: Make sense now. Thank you.